# Best Way to Store Password using C# and MySql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to best store user information and user login and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947618/how-to-best-store-user-information-and-user-login-and-password)
>   [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)

I'm looking for the best methods to securely store passwords on a web-based application using C# and MySql.

I'd love any advice on the best way to implement this, if there are existing dll's i can tap into or things already built into the .net framework.

Also - i'm looking for the way to best store the password while following PCI compliance rules.

Thanks very much...
Loren

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never store the passwords themselves.  [Salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) and hash them before storing.

Answer (score 3):

asp.net has it's own Membership class and it can do a lot of the work for you.

[here's a quick guide i found regarding asp.net membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't know who marked you down, but .Net "Membership" is a good suggestion!  IMHO...